# Hadoop Java - copy file from windows share folder server to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want upload multiple file from Windows share folder server (e.g.  //server_name/folder/)
to my **HDFS** using Java

list of methods I have tried

- org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil set input path = //server_name/folder/
  it says java.io.FileNotFoundException: File //server_name/folder/ does not exist
- FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile (i think this is from local hadoop server to hdfs server)
- IOUtils.copyBytes same as fileUtil >> file does not exist
- a simple File.renameTo same as fileUtil >> file does not exist

  String source_path = "\\server_name\folder\xxx.txt";

  String hdfs_path = "hdfs://HADOOP_SERVER_NAME:Port/myfile/xxx.txt";

  File srcFile = new File(source_path);

  File dstFile = new File(hdfs_path);

  srcFile.renameTo(dstFile);

Do I need to create FTP or How about using `FTPFileSystem`?

Or anyone have better solution Or Sample Code

thank you

Answer (score 1):

FileSystem has copyFromLocal method:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration; 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://abc:9000");

FileSystem fs= FileSystem.get(configuration);
fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/source/directory/"), 
  new Path("/user/hadoop/dir"));
```

Comment: I have tested the method copyFromLocalFile by this sample code
`import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration; 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  
conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://myhdp:9000");

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("\\\\server_name\\folder\\xxx.txt"),
        new Path("/tmp/myusr/dstfolder/xxx.txt"));`

and when i run it on hadoop server it get File not found

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File \\server_name\folder\xxx.txt does not exist`